# Rewritten URL working in a weird way

Tags: .htaccess

These two URLs work right now but they were supposed to show my custom 404 page not found page if extra slashes and some random directory names have been added at the end of the URL like `pending/somethinghere/random1/random2` it works but only for the pending one that I have below, if I add extra slash in developers one like `developers/dev-name/asd`it does not work unless I remove the rule for the other one. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)$ index.php?p=pending&h_=$2&n_=$3 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)$ index.php?p=developers&dev_name=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```